# Oracle APEX main page not loading properly

Tags: oracle, apex

I'm getting [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZDRK.png)  this message in the browser

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your image files are not configured properly. You will want to make sure that you [copied the APEX image files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/htmig/configuring-ords.html#GUID-C070563B-2080-4DB1-A5FB-48B4D1B57D77) to the appropriate directory on the web server.

Based on the error message you are receiving, your image prefix is `/i/` so you will need to place the images within that directory on your web server.

**Update**

If you are having trouble setting up your images directory, you can also [use Oracle's CDN to deliver the APEX files](https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/post/announcing-oracle-apex-static-resources-on-content-delivery-network). Since you are running APEX 19.1, you would want to set your image prefix to `https://static.oracle.com/cdn/apex/19.1.0.00.15/`.

You can do this by running the script `reset_image_prefix.sql` found in the utilities folder of your APEX installation.

Comment: can i see which path is saved against /i/

Comment: Image directory

Comment: how to query image directory

Comment: select * from apex_release VERSION_NO                 19.1.0.00.15
API_COMPATIBILITY 2019.03.31
PATCH_APPLIED         APPLIED

Comment: Your image prefix is `/i/` so you need to set up the web files properly on your Tomcat/Weblogic/ORDS Standalone server.

Comment: Is it necessary...? i install these software Tomcat/Weblogic/ORDS.

Comment: Yes it is required, otherwise you will get the error you are experiencing. Wherever your web server is running, you will need to set up the images directory with the folder named `/i/` and place in the image files (css, javascript, etc.) that came with your APEX installation.

Comment: I have just updated my answer describing how you can reset the image prefix and use Oracle's CDN to delivery the APEX image files.